# Unable to deserialize key data on decoding JWT in Python

Tags: python, oauth, jwt, decode, auth0

I am using Auth0 in my DRF project to generate tokens and authenticate. Everything works fine if I normally encode and decode the tokens. But I have written a method `requires_scope` which determines if the required scope (which the decorator on API tells) for any API. The method is below:

```
def requires_scope(required_scope):
    """Determines if the required scope is present in the Access Token
    Args:
        required_scope (str): The scope required to access the resource
    """
    def require_scope(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            token = get_token_auth_header(args[0])
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, verify=False, algorithms=settings.AUTH0_ALGORITHMS)
            if decoded.get("scope"):
                token_scopes = decoded["scope"].split()
                for token_scope in token_scopes:
                    if token_scope == required_scope:
                        return f(*args, **kwargs)
            response = JsonResponse({'message': 'You don\'t have access to this resource'})
            response.status_code = 403
            return response
        return decorated
    return require_scope
```

now when I use the decorator on API for any specific scope, it does not decode the JWT and shows the following `ValueError` error:

```
('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=75497580, lib=9, reason=108, reason_text=b'error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line')])
```

This is my decoding method:

```
def jwt_decode_token(token):
    header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    jwks = requests.get('https://{}/.well-known/jwks.json'.format(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN)).json()
    public_key = None
    for jwk in jwks['keys']:
        if jwk['kid'] == header['kid']:
            public_key = jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(json.dumps(jwk))
            # public_key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + jwk['x5c'][0] + "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
            # print(public_key)

    if public_key is None:
        raise Exception('Public key not found.')

    issuer = 'https://{}/'.format(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN)
    return jwt.decode(
        token,
        public_key,
        audience=settings.AUTH0_TOKEN_API_AUDIENCE,
        issuer=issuer,
        algorithms=['RS256']
    )
```

and this is the payload I am passing to API Call (it contains the scope):

```
payload = f"{{\"client_id\":\"{settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_KEY}\",\
                    \"client_secret\":\"{settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_AUTH0_SECRET}\",\
                    \"audience\":\"{settings.AUTH0_TOKEN_API_AUDIENCE}\",\
                    \"grant_type\":\"password\",\
                    \"username\":\"{email}\",\
                    \"password\":\"{password}\",\
                    \"scope\":\"read:messages\"}}"
```

What's wrong I am doing? Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it complains about the key is because it is still trying to do the verification. In order to correctly disable this with pyjwt is:

```
jwt.decode(token, algorithms=["RS256"], options={"verify_signature": False})
```

See the pyjwt documentation (interestingly, I cannot skip the algorithms block): https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation